# Webcomponents :host:hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there a way to add a css :hover effect on webcompoenents (not from the parent).

I have following example code

```
window.customElements.define('a-b', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
        <style>
          :host {
            display: block;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background: red;
          }
          :host:hover {
            background: blue;
          }
          :host::selection {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
          }
        </style>
        <slot></slot>
      `;
  }
}
```

The `:host::selection` property works as expected. But the `:host:hover` does not seem to have any effect.

I know there are workarounds to this problem like:

- wrapping everything inside a `div`
- applying the `:hover` effect at the parent stylesheet

But I wanted to know if I am just missing something (since this does not seem too complex) for the sake of cleaner code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the sake of cleaner code, use instead the [`:host()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()) syntax since `:hover` is a pseudo-class applied to the Custom Element. It is then selectable with:

```
:host(:hover) { ... }
```

Example:

```js
window.customElements.define('a-b', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .innerHTML = `
           <style>
              :host(:hover) {
                color: white;
                background-color: blue;
              }       
          </style>
          <slot></slot>`
  }
})
```

```html
<a-b>Hello World</a-b>
```

Comment: In case anyone using Angular with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` I can confirm that this fix works in the scss file. I did have to make a separate `:host(:hover)` node though - couldn't make it work with `:host &(:hover)`